# Vue.Js How to see events fired within components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

*I am a noob so please don't crucify me for such a basic question.*

I'm using a component on a new vue project (https://northwalker.github.io/vue-hotel-datepicker/). It is in the app and it appears to be working however I can't seem to get any of the values. On the github page it says the property I want is:

```
startDate
   Type: Date or String
   Default: undefined
   The start date of given date range.
```

So, I would assume that anywhere I want this to be displayed in the page I should just use interpolation. Directly underneath where I add the component I am doing:

```
<VueHotelDatepicker/>
  {{ startDate }}
```

and I am getting the error:

> Property or method "startDate" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

and nothing is loading.

how do get get the values out of the component?

Comment: regarding `how to see` - check out the [vue-devtools (chrome)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) or the one for [firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/vue-js-devtools/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass an event to handle value change.
Something like this:

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    // You need to catch value change, VueHotelDatepicker provide event to do that
    // Here I use event confirm
    <VueHotelDatepicker @confirm="confirm"/>
    {{ startDate }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// Import component to use
import VueHotelDatepicker from "@northwalker/vue-hotel-datepicker";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    // Define it, you can change alias name
    VueHotelDatepicker
  },
  data() {
    return {
      // Init data
      startDate: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    // Function handle value changed when we click confirm
    // You can confuse where is dateRange from. It is defined in document
    // {
    //    start: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    //    end: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    // }
    confirm(dateRange) {
      // When click confirm, update startDate
      // Vue use 2-way binding data
      // It will auto re-render to reflect on screen
      this.startDate = dateRange.start;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

You can see list event here: https://github.com/northwalker/vue-hotel-datepicker#events

I made a sample about handling value changed
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-rdw9t

Comment: First of all. Thank you. That works. Second could you perhaps edit your answer and explain to me what each bit is doing. You linked to the events section on github, I saw that. But nowhere does your code mention `update`. Again I am new to vue and front end dev so this could be obvious but I just do not get how your code works.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your time helping me.